# Can a FileChooser in java modify a for loop?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have this program that puts information into an excel file, I have a version where I do not implement a filechooser and the excel that throws prints the info like this in the excel sheet:

-line1

-line2

-line3

But the new version that I added filechooser it throws the information like this in the excel sheet:

-line1

(blank row)

(blank row)

(blank row)

-line2

(blank row)

(blank row)

(blank row)

(blank row)

(blank row)

-line3

I do not know if the filechooser is the cause, but it has to be because I used the same code as before without any change. I tried changing the counters but it did not work. I hope you can help me with some clues about it.

I have this code for the filechoosers:

```
JFileChooser chooser1 = new JFileChooser1();
       int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser1);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this PDF file: " +
        chooser1.getSelectedFile().getName());
}

File file = chooser2.getSelectedFile();

JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser2();
       int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser2);
if(returnVal2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this excel file: " +
        chooser2.getSelectedFile().getName());
}


File Excel = chooser2.getSelectedFile();

JFileChooser chooser3 = new JFileChooser1();
       int returnVal3 = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser3);
chooser3.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this destination: " +
        chooser3.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
File path = chooser3.getCurrentDirectory();

//Then here starts the other process
```

Yes, I use 3 filechoosers in this program, 1 to select pdf file, then the other to select an excel file and then the third to select a directory to store the results. It appear one after another.

The first block of the program is the filechoosers, then from the pdf extracts information that will be stored in a copy of the excel selected previously and then throws an Output excel with the information. But that information is not one line after another there are blank rows, like I explained before

Comment: there is no way a JFileChooser can alter a for loop

Comment: Your concern should be a line where you write filechoosers data into excel

Comment: @IvanPronin you were right, I had so much time looking at the code that I slipped there, thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what `chooser` is, but, assuming it's a 4th JFileChooser, I believe the lines like

```
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser1);
```

are wrong - these are always opening `chooser` and not the JFileChooser given as argument. Change to:

```
int returnVal = chooser1.showOpenDialog(null);  
// or use the main frame/window instead of null
```

The argument is the parent component for the dialog.

Obs: you could reuse the JFileChooser after calling `showOpenDialog` and getting he selected file/directory.

Unable to write anything about the loop since none was posted in the question...